# how to open file and put string in the end of each line in php

Tags: php, file

Please tell me how to open file and put string in the end of each line in php 
Is this possible?

And who can make me understand this code?

```
f = open('./ampo.txt', 'r+')
with open('./ampo.txt') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        f.insert(0, 'EDF ')
f.close
```

Comment: That is not even remotely PHP

Comment: how about using `'a+'` instead of `'r+'`

Comment: Looks like Python to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to append to each line in the file you'll have to read the file in and then override it. I actually recommend writing to a different file and if you choose to do that just alter the file name in the fopen call.

```
$lines = file("./amp.txt");
$fp = fopen("./amp.txt", "w");
foreach($lines as $line) {
    fwrite($fp, substr($line,0,-1) . "EDF" . substr($line,-1));
}
fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you want

```
$myFile = "testFile.txt";  // The file
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file"); // Open it
$stringData = "New Stuff 1\n"; // Your data
fwrite($fh, $stringData); // Write to file
$stringData = "New Stuff 2\n"; // Your data
fwrite($fh, $stringData); // Write again
fclose($fh); // Close it
```

the A (append) in fopen, will make sure things get appended to the file